# Query optimisation / rewriting

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I need to rewrite the following queries for optimization but I'm having a little trouble

`SELECT w.wname, SUM(w.price) sold_total, FROM wine w GROUP BY w.wname;`

`SELECT * from class WHERE CID = 'RIES ' OR CID = 'CHARDN' OR CID = 'PINOT';`

I think i need to create some kinda object for the first one and a bind variable for the second but I'm just not sure. Also unsure of best syntax.

Would love some help

Comment: In the second query please start from replacing * with columns you really need

Comment: The first isn't a valid SQL statement.  You've got an extra comma after `sold_total`.  I'm not sure what the goal of the homework here is.  Are you really trying to rewrite queries?  Because the first query seems like a perfectly reasonable way to express the query.  Or is it to optimize the queries?  In which case we'd need to begin with what are you trying to optimize (is the homework to reduce logical reads, for example?) and what are the query plans?

Comment: Yeah the point is to write them and use knowledge to optimise them

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the sum or w.price outside of the query then call it?

Answer (score 1):

Your first query:

```sql
SELECT w.wname, SUM(w.price) sold_total FROM wine w GROUP BY w.wname
```

cannot really be optimized, because it is using the `SUM()` function with aggregation, and ultimately every record in the table must be involved.  Since there is no filtering here, there isn't much advantage to using a index, and Oracle would likely just decide to do a full table scan.  For the second query:

```sql
SELECT * from class WHERE CID = 'RIES ' OR CID = 'CHARDN' OR CID = 'PINOT';
```

you may consider adding the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_class ON class (CID);
```

This would cover the `WHERE` clause, which is the filtering step, letting the query execute faster.

Comment: It probably would not make a difference in what the optimizer ultimately comes up with, but simply an easier to maintain alternative to 'WHERE CID = 'RIES ' OR CID = 'CHARDN' OR CID = 'PINOT'  would be WHERE CID IN ('RIES', CHARDN', 'PINOT')